# Calling a REST API with C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, json.net

**Background:** I have this school project where I want to make a recipe web app using https://developer.edamam.com/edamam-docs-recipe-api.

**What I've done so far:**

1. Made a get request in Postman and took the JSON data and generated C# with json2csharp.com

```
namespace EdamaAPI.Models
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public string q { get; set; }
        public int from { get; set; }
        public int to { get; set; }
        public Params _params { get; set; }
        public bool more { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
        public Hit[] hits { get; set; }
    }

    public class Params
    {
        public object[] sane { get; set; }
        public string[] q { get; set; }
        public string[] app_key { get; set; }
        public string[] health { get; set; }
        public string[] from { get; set; }
        public string[] to { get; set; }
        public string[] calories { get; set; }
        public string[] app_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hit
    {
        public Recipe recipe { get; set; }
        public bool bookmarked { get; set; }
        public bool bought { get; set; }
    }

    public class Recipe
    {
        public string uri { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string shareAs { get; set; }
        public float yield { get; set; }
        public string[] dietLabels { get; set; }
        public string[] healthLabels { get; set; }
        public object[] cautions { get; set; }
        public string[] ingredientLines { get; set; }
        public Ingredient[] ingredients { get; set; }
        public float calories { get; set; }
        public float totalWeight { get; set; }
        public Totalnutrients totalNutrients { get; set; }
        public Totaldaily totalDaily { get; set; }
        public Digest[] digest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Totalnutrients
    {
        public ENERC_KCAL ENERC_KCAL { get; set; }
        public FAT FAT { get; set; }
        public FASAT FASAT { get; set; }
        public FATRN FATRN { get; set; }
        public FAMS FAMS { get; set; }
        public FAPU FAPU { get; set; }
        public CHOCDF CHOCDF { get; set; }
        public SUGAR SUGAR { get; set; }
        public PROCNT PROCNT { get; set; }
        public CHOLE CHOLE { get; set; }
        public NA NA { get; set; }
        public CA CA { get; set; }
        public MG MG { get; set; }
        public K K { get; set; }
        public FE FE { get; set; }
        public ZN ZN { get; set; }
        public P P { get; set; }
        public VITA_RAE VITA_RAE { get; set; }
        public VITC VITC { get; set; }
        public THIA THIA { get; set; }
        public RIBF RIBF { get; set; }
        public NIA NIA { get; set; }
        public VITB6A VITB6A { get; set; }
        public FOLDFE FOLDFE { get; set; }
        public FOLFD FOLFD { get; set; }
        public VITB12 VITB12 { get; set; }
        public VITD VITD { get; set; }
        public TOCPHA TOCPHA { get; set; }
        public VITK1 VITK1 { get; set; }
        public FIBTG FIBTG { get; set; }
    }

    public class ENERC_KCAL
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FAT
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FASAT
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FATRN
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FAMS
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FAPU
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class CHOCDF
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class SUGAR
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class PROCNT
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class CHOLE
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class NA
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class CA
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class MG
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class K
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FE
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class ZN
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class P
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITA_RAE
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITC
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class THIA
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class RIBF
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class NIA
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITB6A
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FOLDFE
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FOLFD
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITB12
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITD
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class TOCPHA
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITK1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FIBTG
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Totaldaily
    {
        public ENERC_KCAL1 ENERC_KCAL { get; set; }
        public FAT1 FAT { get; set; }
        public FASAT1 FASAT { get; set; }
        public CHOCDF1 CHOCDF { get; set; }
        public PROCNT1 PROCNT { get; set; }
        public CHOLE1 CHOLE { get; set; }
        public NA1 NA { get; set; }
        public CA1 CA { get; set; }
        public MG1 MG { get; set; }
        public K1 K { get; set; }
        public FE1 FE { get; set; }
        public ZN1 ZN { get; set; }
        public P1 P { get; set; }
        public VITA_RAE1 VITA_RAE { get; set; }
        public VITC1 VITC { get; set; }
        public THIA1 THIA { get; set; }
        public RIBF1 RIBF { get; set; }
        public NIA1 NIA { get; set; }
        public VITB6A1 VITB6A { get; set; }
        public FOLDFE1 FOLDFE { get; set; }
        public VITB121 VITB12 { get; set; }
        public VITD1 VITD { get; set; }
        public TOCPHA1 TOCPHA { get; set; }
        public VITK11 VITK1 { get; set; }
        public FIBTG1 FIBTG { get; set; }
    }

    public class ENERC_KCAL1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FAT1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FASAT1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class CHOCDF1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class PROCNT1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class CHOLE1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class NA1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class CA1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class MG1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class K1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FE1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class ZN1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class P1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITA_RAE1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITC1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class THIA1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class RIBF1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class NIA1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITB6A1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FOLDFE1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITB121
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITD1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class TOCPHA1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class VITK11
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class FIBTG1
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ingredient
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public float weight { get; set; }
    }

    public class Digest
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string tag { get; set; }
        public string schemaOrgTag { get; set; }
        public float total { get; set; }
        public bool hasRDI { get; set; }
        public float daily { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
        public Sub[] sub { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sub
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string tag { get; set; }
        public string schemaOrgTag { get; set; }
        public float total { get; set; }
        public bool hasRDI { get; set; }
        public float daily { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }

}
```

2. Sending an get request to access the data and deserialize it.

```
public class RecipeController : Controller
{           
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<Recipe> RecInfo = new List<Recipe>();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Passing service base url  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.edamam.com");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=a88093f8&app_key=4513de36c431f9936462ef4391f631e4&from=0&to=3&calories=gte%20591,%20lte%20722&health=alcohol-free");

            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                var name = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                RecInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Recipe>>(name); 
            }

            //returning the employee list to view  
            return View(RecInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

3. Autogenerated View with Visual studio.

```
@model IEnumerable<EdamaAPI.Models.Recipe>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.uri)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.label)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.image)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.source)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.url)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.shareAs)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.yield)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.calories)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.totalWeight)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.uri)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.label)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.image)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.source)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.url)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shareAs)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.yield)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.calories)
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.totalWeight)
       </td>
       <td>
           @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
           @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
           @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */               })
       </td>
   </tr>
}  
</table>
```

When I try to run the project this error occurs:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'EdamaAPI.Models.Recipe', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EdamaAPI.Models.Ingredient]'.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'EdamaAPI.Models.Recipe', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EdamaAPI.Models.Ingredient]'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +175
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

I've been searching for hours on Google without luck and I could really use a guiding hand right now! If there is any information that I forgot to include, tell me and I'll get that sorted out right away.

Comment: Where does it throw that exception? The stack trace would be helpful

Comment: @less no it is a sequence, just badly named.

Comment: All those classes with the same properties :O.... Please use something like an enum to define the type as an additional property and have only 1 class instead of ~20.

Comment: We might be missing something here... Like, you are being redirected to an unexpected view..? Where is the view you are displaying located in the project? Search your project for "@model IEnumerable<EdamaAPI.Models.Ingredient>" in cshtml files.

Comment: Where exactly did you get this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says it all:

**Look at the exception**

*The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'EdamaAPI.Models.Recipe', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EdamaAPI.Models.Ingredient]'.*

Look at the model:

```
@model IEnumerable<EdamaAPI.Models.Recipe>
```

You pass a recipe model to the view while the view required ingredient model.

**This will work:**

```
public class RecipeController : Controller
    {

        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<Ingredient> RecInfo = new List<Ingredient>();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.edamam.com");

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=a88093f8&app_key=4513de36c431f9936462ef4391f631e4&from=0&to=3&calories=gte%20591,%20lte%20722&health=alcohol-free");

                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                    var name = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                    RecInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Ingredient>>(name);

                }
                //returning the employee list to view  
                return View(RecInfo);
            }
        }
}
```

**but that's not what you need**, as you need *recipe model*. 
Change your action to accept a generic Recipe list.